# spring security oidc oath2 Okta login invalid user response

Tags: spring-security, okta

I am following this example to secure application without springboot [spring mvc + spring security with Okta login without springboot](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/12/secure-java-ee-rest-api)

When I login to the `http://localhost:8080/myappContext/` it takes me to Okta logic screen. I enter either one of the user in assign list and click "sign in" it signs in then shows following error.

[image]

any help is appreciated.

**Following is my Okta application configuration**

I have Okta developer account application is setup as web application with oidc,

1. client authentication is "client secret".
2. Grant type is ("Client credentials", "authorization code", implicit(hybrid) -> allow             id token with implicit grant type, allow access token with implicit grant type)
3. sign in direct uri is "http://localhost:8080/myappContext/login/oauth2/code/okta
4. signet redirect uri is "http://localhost:8080/myappContext"
5. login initiated by "App only"
6. Federation Broker Mode is disabled.
7. Okta api scopes granted none.
8. user assignments user1 and user 2 (2 users)
9. Groups: every one

**Following is my code detail**

```
Spring 5 security with OIDC login for Okta.
spring-framework version 5.3.x
spring security version 5.6.x
```

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java**

```java
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
    extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfiguration.class);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
okta.client-id={clientId}
okta.client-secret={clientSecret}
okta.issuer-uri=https://{yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/default
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final String clientSecret;
    private final String clientId;
    private final String issuerUri;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(@Value("${okta.issuer-uri}") String issuerUri,
            @Value("${okta.client-id}") String clientId,
            @Value("${okta.client-secret}") String clientSecret) {
        this.issuerUri = issuerUri;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    }

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2Login();
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService() {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository());
    }

    

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        ClientRegistration okta = getRegistration();
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(okta);
    }

    public ClientRegistration getRegistration(){
    
        ClientRegistrations.fromOidcIssuerLocation(Objects.requireNonNull(issuerUri))
            .registrationId("okta")
            .clientId(clientId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .build();
    }
}
```

**My controller**

```java
public class SecureController{
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String authenticated(Principal user){
       return "home";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/login/oauth2/code/okta")
    public String callback(Principal user){
      return "authenticated"
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but you might find more recent information about Spring (Boot) apps OAuth2 configuration from [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#securing-spring-applications-with-oauth2). What you'll find there works with Okta (and Auth0, Keycloak, or any OpenID Provider). Building solutions around `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` like you're doing right now is definitely not future proof (this adapter disappeared in Spring 6)